# After purchasing all the upgrades and characters what is the use of gold?

Tags: temple-run-2

I've recently purchased all the upgrades and characters in Temple Run 2. And I realized that I have no idea why do I need coins now. Can anyone tell me what's the use of these coins after purchasing all the upgrades(power ups) and characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After unlocks & upgrades, there is no real use for gold (unless you need to purchase characters (which has been completed)).

I guess it's just stackable.

Edit: The Head Start is a useful one to purchase before each game.

Comment: Also they can be used for the Speed powerup right when you start. I've found this to be useful for completing daily challenges (like running a certain amount of distance).

Comment: @SSHThis That is true - I completely forgot.

Comment: @EfcSeany You should add that point to your answer.

Comment: @SSHThis it's a `Head Start` and `Mega Head Start` :) But doing daily(and weekly) challenges now is just... Not the same as before. Yes, I can get some coins and/or gems. But why do I need it? :p

Comment: @Novarg I share your sentiment :) I am also at a point where I have like half a million coins and 500 gems. I still play it just for the satisfaction of achieving the challenges. But you're right they should add some more things you can unlock or buy.

Comment: @Novarg A bit outdated now, for sure, but if this answer helped, please mark it as accepted for possible future viewers. :)

Comment: @Sean there you go :)

Answer (score 1):

Coins are still worth picking up because they add to your score.

[This article](http://www.mathematicalmischief.com/2013/01/its-calculator-time-temple-run-2/) over at Mathematical Mischief shows how scores are calculated during a run. The formula is sort of large, but one of the components of a score is coins, which are each worth five points multiplied by your multiplier bonus.

Assuming that the calculation on points is correct (which I haven't taken the time to double check, not realistically ever will), picking up coins could be worth a lot of points over the course of a run. So while they may no longer be useful outside of each run, they can help you to keep pushing your scores higher.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the link you provided describes score for temple run 1, not 2

Comment: @Novarg Yep. I edited to include information for Temple Run 2.